# Angular 2: Possibility click on disabled input field when dropdown menu was opened

Tags: javascript, html, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

Maybe You know why or what can I do with that difference between Chrome\Firefox browsers.

When I created input field and `(click)="functionExample()"` function:

```
functionExample(){

document.getElementById("inputField").disabled=true;

}
```

`functionExample()` is called when the dropdown menu is open (dropdown menu open -> main input field disable).

In that situation on chrome browser, I can click on disabled main input field (dropdown menu was closed after id)

on Firefox browser - I can't click on input field after disabled it - and dropdown menu is still open.

I would like to have that same behaviour on Chrome browser.

Comment: Use readonly attribute instead of disabled

Comment: But with readonly property, there is no disable shadow effect.

Comment: U can write css using [readyonly] selector

Comment: Great, working perfectly. Thank You!